# How to retrieve common key value pairs from two hashmaps

Tags: java

I have two hashmaps:

```
Map<String, String> mapA = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String, String> mapB = new HashMap<String, String>();
TreeSet<String> uniquekeys = new TreeSet<String>();
mapA.put("1","value1");
mapA.put("2","value2");
mapA.put("3","value3");
mapA.put("4","value4");
mapA.put("5","value5");
mapA.put("6","value6");
mapA.put("7","value7");
mapA.put("8","value8");
mapA.put("9","value9");
mapB.put("1","value1");
mapB.put("2","value2");
mapB.put("3","value3");
mapB.put("4","value4");
mapB.put("5","value5");
```

To get the common key value pairs from the two hashmaps, I have written the below logic:

```
uniquekeys.addAll(mapA.keySet());
uniquekeys.addAll(mapB.keySet());
```

and then use the keys from the `treeset: uniquekeys`  to retrieve unique key value pairs from mapA & mapB.
But this is not giving me the details of all the keys from mapA. I understand this way is flawed but I couldn't come up with a proper logic.
Could anyone let me know how can I retrieve key value pairs that are common in mapA and mapB into a new HashMap ?

Comment: What would the new Map contain for the common keys? The values of mapA or the values of mapB? Or should it contain only key-value pairs having the same key and value in both Maps?

Comment: The new map should contain the key value pairs that are common in both mapA and mapB.

Comment: @Sidhartha have you try retainAll?

Comment: Do you mind using an external library ? Google Guava provides tools to compare sets : https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Java 8 Streams in the following way:

```
Map<String, String> commonMap = mapA.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(x -> mapB.containsKey(x.getKey()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getKey(), x -> x.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below logic :

```
Map<String, String> common = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for(String key : mapA.keySet()) {
            if(mapB.get(key) !=null ) {
                if(mapA.get(key).equals(mapB.get(key))) {
                    common.put(key, mapA.get(key));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Simple and better

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding all keys to a TreeSet, you can fill the TreeSet with common values:

```
uniquekeys.addAll(mapA.keySet());
uniquekeys.retainAll(mapB.keySet());
```

This way, the keys contained in A but not B will be removed. Know you've got your TreeSet, you can do what you want.

However, you can also create your HashMap without TreeSet, as @Ramesh and @NiVeR suggest

Answer (score 0):

Use Guava Util Sets

```
Set<String> intersectionSet = Sets.intersection(firstSet, secondSet);
```